# Export data to CSV column

Tags: powershell

I have 2 arrays - $Hostnames and $Ipaddresses.

My $Hostname array displays a list of computer hostnames, and my $Ipaddresses array displays a list of ipaddresses that corresponds to the $Hostnames array.

I have an existing CSV file with 2 headers - "Hostname" and "Ipaddress"

I would like the 2 arrays exported to my CSV file with 2 columns. One column with the Hostnames and the other column with the Ipaddresses.

There are multiple answers to similar questions on this site and other sites that I have visited, but none of them have aided me thus far.

This is the closest that I have gotten...

```
$CSV = Import-Csv -path C:\temp\scripts\ReimageCheck\results.csv

foreach ($column in $CSV) {

generate column 1 value.

    $column."Hostname" = $Hostnames

generate column 2 value.

    $column."Ipaddress" = $Ipaddresses

} 

$CSV | Export-Csv -Path C:\temp\scripts\ReimageCheck\Results2.csv
```

But when I open the "Results2.csv" all of the information is a bunch of garbled symbols dispersed all over the place. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Even better if we can eliminate the need for a pre-existing csv file and just create a new csv file with the 2 columns of information.

Comment: Garbage output sounds like encoding problem. Please edit the question and show sample input and the garbled output. Use a screen shot as last resort for the output (it's harder to read than text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your two arrays are actually the same size...

You could iterate over them in a for loop and add a new `pscustomobject` to an array, then save that out as CSV.

```
$data = @()
$hostnames = @('h1','h2','h3')
$ipaddresses = @('1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2','3.3.3.3')

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $hostnames.Count; $i++)
{
    $data += [pscustomobject]@{'HostName'=$hostnames[$i]; 'IpAddress'=$ipaddresses[$i]}
}

# test
$data | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation

#
#$data | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\scripts\ReimageCheck\Results2.csv'
```

There are a few ways to improve this algorithm for speed, etc, but this shows things in the most straightforward manner.  Use the ISE or VSCode to debug and understand the code by walking through it.  Also search using `Get-Help` for other things that are new to you.

Answer (score 0):

The above will be very inefficient for large CSV files as the array $data is recreated for each iteration of the loop.

A more efficient solution would be

```
$hostnames = @('h1','h2','h3')
$ipaddresses = @('1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2','3.3.3.3')

$data = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $hostnames.Count; $i++)
{
    [pscustomobject]@{'HostName'=$hostnames[$i]; 'IpAddress'=$ipaddresses[$i]}
}

# test
$data | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation

#
#$data | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\scripts\ReimageCheck\Results2.csv'
```